# How to toggle and hover a side menu?

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, click, toggle

I am currently having a sidemenu on a website. The side menu can be opened by hovering a specific area, and it closes if un-hovering. This works fine, but I also want it to open if I click a specific area, which also works. But I want it to close again if clicking this area again, and this is my problem right now.

```
$.fn.boxLid = function(options){
  var box = new BoxLid(options);
  return this.each(function(){
    $(this).hover(box.open, box.close) && $('#id').click(box.open);
  });
};
```

I used the click function so far, because .toggle(box.open, box.close); won't work. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: create a [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) demo

Answer (score 0):

There is no jQuery second click handler so you might wanna use an indicator to get this done. Something like this:

```
$.fn.boxLid = function (options) {
    var box = new BoxLid(options);
    var open = false;
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).hover(box.open, box.close); 
        $('#id').click(function(){
           if(open){
             box.close;
             open = false;
           }else{
             box.open
             open = true;
           }
        });
    });
};
```